# NopCommerce upgrade from 2.3 to 3.8

Tags: sql-server, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.80

I am currently using NopCommerce v2.3 with a lot of custom development for a fully functional e-commerce website. I'm supposed to be taking care of its upgrade to v3.8. I am aware that there are SQL scripts released to upgrade across minor versions. Any help or approach on how the custom developed components can be upgraded will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major methods of customization

1. Using partial
2. Code  plugin

If you have done partial code with default code, it's bit hard to upgrade and need to more taking care of, with a plugin it's bit easier.

Is it possible to wrap your code within a plugin? if *yes* then I recommend you to create one or more plugin(s), if not then you can upgrade your code first to next released version and so on..and then finally upgrade it to 3.80.

Moreover, you have to run upgrade script of each version followed by the next version script.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Turning my code into a plugin doesn't seem a feasible solution. I think I'll have to use partial. Thanks for the answer!